# How to disable HTTP POST REQUEST of oData APIs?

Tags: java, spring, api, odata, olingo

I'm setting up a new Java application using oData and ServletRegistrationBean.
I'd like to disable the option of receiving POST request and to allow only GET requests.

Where should I set it up?
Can I create kind of a whitelist/blacklist?

```java
ServletRegistrationBean odataServRegstration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet(), "/odata/*");
Map<String, String> initParameters = new HashMap<>();
initParameters.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", "org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.app.ODataApplication");
initParameters.put("org.apache.olingo.odata2.service.factory", "com.sap.context.JPAServiceFactory");
odataServRegstration.setInitParameters(initParameters);
return odataServRegstration;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring Security you can easily configure that for example only users of role admin are able to make non GetRequests. I will provide an example soon unless you find it on the net before that. Other unseres will receive a 403.

A minimalistic example would be:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
          .and()
          .httpBasic()
        ;
    }
```

Pay attention to `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").hasRole("ADMIN")`.

Comment: Yes please, I'd like to see your example.

Answer (score 0):

It is my method to disable POST option.

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(method = {GET,  PATCH, DELETE})
public void service(final HttpServletRequest servletRequest, final HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException {

    try {........................
```